# Shopify API refund email notifications

Tags: shopify

I am using the Transactions API to create refunds, then using the Order API to cancel the order. The cancel part generates a confirmation email to the customer according to what we have set up as our template just fine, however, the refund email is never sent. If we refund an order manually through the admin portal, the email is sent, but not via the Transactions API.

This email should be sent automatically, without having to send in a "notify_customer" parameter, correct?

Ben

Answer (score 0):

The refund api has a boolean 'notify' property.

```
{
  refund:{
    notify: true, 
    ...
  }
}
```